# How can I find the highest value from a List of float and get the value index and then draw a circle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

[RequireComponent(typeof(LineRenderer))]
public class DrawCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public int segments = 50;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float xradius = 5;
    [Range(0, 50)]
    public float yradius = 5;
    public bool minimumRequireRadius = false;
    LineRenderer line;
    private List<float> radiusList = new List<float>();

    void Start()
    {
        HighestRadius(transform);
        float highest = radiusList.Max();
        float resultRadius = radiusList[5] / 4;
        xradius = resultRadius;
        yradius = resultRadius;

        line = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.positionCount = segments + 1;
        line.useWorldSpace = false;
        CreatePoints();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        CreatePoints();
    }

    void CreatePoints()
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        float angle = 20f;

        for (int i = 0; i < (segments + 1); i++)
        {
            x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * xradius;
            z = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * yradius;

            line.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, 0, z));

            angle += (360f / segments + 1);
        }
    }

    private void HighestRadius(Transform root)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in root)
        {
            HighestRadius(child);

            var rend = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            if (rend != null)
            {
                var rends = child.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.x;
                radiusList.Add(rends);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this part:

```
float highest = radiusList.Max();
float resultRadius = radiusList[5] / 4;
```

I want to get the highest value number from the List in this case it's 407 and that's a bit strange. When I loop over the childs in this loop HighestRadius one of the values of the sizes is 407. But all the objects are not even close to 100 in size.

Then I want to get the resultRadius:

```
float resultRadius = radiusList[5] / 4;
```

So it will be: float resultRadius = highest / 4;

Last thing is to set the xradius and yradius to the resultRadius and draw a circle. But I'm not sure if dividing it by 4 is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well ... a few comments:

- You are taking the bounds of the Renderers attached to a Transform, which seems a bit odd to me. Given that the Renderer represents the object in space, wouldn't it make more sense to start with the Renderer and simply take it's bounds? Then there is no need to proceed hierarchically. Your code doesn't say where "transform' is coming from in the Start method. It would make more sense to me to hand a Renderer into the constructor of the class.
- In the expression angle += (360f / segments + 1), you are dividing by "segments" and then adding 1. Would you not want to divide by (segments + 1) instead?